# Segmentation error when trying to rebuild boot sector with TestDisk

Tags: testdisk

I've been trying to recover a windows 10 C: drive using Ubuntu 20.04.4 and TestDisk. Drive became RAW for no apparent reason. I created a disk image using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of="/media/jmac150/New Volume/image.dd" bs=4K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

I then ran TestDisk against it.

TestDisk advised that both boot sector and backup were ok. However, when I tried to rebuild the boot sector, it failed with a "Segmentation fault":

[image: screenshot of Segmentation fault]

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Hello. Ubuntu tools will not fix this Windows disk. Nor is this a Ubuntu question. You need to try and fix it with Windows tools.

Comment: Why will Ubuntu not fix problem and why is this not an Ubuntu question? I have researched and it would seem that Ubuntu and TestDisk is the better option. Windows tools have failed so far.